# asp.net core webapi MsTest

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, mstest

I am try to use MsTest to test asp.net core webapi

```
  [TestClass]
public class IndexControllerTest
{
    private readonly WebHostTestHelp _webhost;

    public IndexControllerTest( )
    {
        _webhost =new  WebHostTestHelp();
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task GetindexstringhttpTest()
    {
        var res = await _webhost._http.GetAsync("api/Index/indexstring");
        var result = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Assert.AreEqual("OK", res.StatusCode.ToString());
        Assert.AreEqual("indexstring", result);
        res.isCodeOk();
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task GetindexresultdatahttpTest()
    {
        var res = await _webhost._http.GetAsync("api/Index/indexresultdata");
        var result = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Assert.AreEqual("OK", res.StatusCode.ToString());
        res.isCodeOk();
    }
}
```

I use this code to test webapi.My purpose is to see console.WriteLine.
But asp.net core have Logging with default output.
So I see this.

```
 warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
      Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
info: DataBase.FilterHelp.LogFilterAttribute[0]
       0 | zekj.Controllers.IndexController.indexresultdata (zekj) | {"state":"查询","affectRow":0,"countRow":1,"message":{"data":"2222indexresultdata"}}
{"state":"查询","affectRow":0,"countRow":1,"message":{"data":"2222indexresultdata"}}
```

I do not need to see warn,info or other.
Please tell me how to do.Thanks.

I change my code and it work .

```
_testserver = new TestServer(WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder().ConfigureLogging(x => x.ClearProviders()).UseStartup<zekjRestaurant.Startup>());
```

Comment: Can you include the code for your WebHostTestHelp class?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a setting in your app settings json, something to do with level of logging that’s defaulted. Can you share your settings for logging and then I can update my answer or you can just trying changing level to error.

Comment: I change my TestServer code ,it work ,Thanks for reminding.

Comment: You are welcome, please upvote if that worked for you. 